# Is it allowed to reuse pg QueryFile multiple times

Tags: javascript, postgresql, ecmascript-6, pg, pg-promise

Am I allowed to reuse type [QueryFile](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/QueryFile.html) of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise)?

Eg.

```
const pgp = require(`pg-promise`)(options);
const QueryFile = pgp.QueryFile;

const db = pgp(config.DB);
const query =  new QueryFile('queryPath/some.sql', { minify: true });

// running sql query
db.any(query, []);
db.any(query, []);
db.any(query, []);
db.any(query, []);    
db.any(query, []);
```

Currently, I am creating new QueryFile every time I want to execute it.
e.g.

```
db.any(new QueryFile('queryPath/some.sql', { minify: true }), []);
db.any(new QueryFile('queryPath/some.sql', { minify: true }), []);
db.any(new QueryFile('queryPath/some.sql', { minify: true }), []);
db.any(new QueryFile('queryPath/some.sql', { minify: true }), []);
```

Are there any cons if I reuse same query multiple times?

Comment: Did you read the `IMPORTANT` section of [its API](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/QueryFile.html)? The type is a virtual link to a file, to be created only once.

Comment: This usage pattern is horrible, as I explain in the answer below ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it allowed to reuse pg QueryFile multiple times?

No, not allowed, insisted upon!

---

Type [QueryFile](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/QueryFile.html) represents a virtual link to the file, and its use offers many advantages - [as documented](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#query-files).

The two keys features that concern this question are:

> - Parsing and minifying SQL (options `minify/compress`), for early error detection and compact queries.
> - Changes in external SQL can be automatically re-loaded (option `debug`), without restarting the app.

The first one loads the file, parses and minifies it, if option `minify`/`compress` is provided. This takes time and the IO, and should not be done multiple times, as it would be pointless anyway.

The second point allows it to be used as a virtual link that can automatically detect any file changes while in development mode (option `debug`), and to automatically reload and prepare the file. In a development environment this feature is priceless, preventing you from reloading the app whenever an external SQL file changes.

---

So the cons are:

- Creating unnecessary IO (extra file reads + SQL parsing and minification). And in your example it is even worse - you are doing it every time when executing a query.
- Losing the key features for which type [QueryFile](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/QueryFile.html) was designed (auto-reload becomes impossible)

---

And when you re-create [QueryFile](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/QueryFile.html) type for the same file, you are using the type against its most useful purposes. And this is why it will report a warning for you as `Creating a duplicate QueryFile object for the same file`.

You should set up a separate structure for SQL files, like it is shown in [pg-promise-demo](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise-demo), see [here](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise-demo/tree/master/JavaScript/db/sql).